# NMAP sees open ports, but netstat doesn't show listeners on them

Tags: windows, port, nmap

I just scanned my PC remotely with zenmap, and see a number of open ports not related to any services I'm providing.

Redacted list of ports:

```
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
32/tcp    filtered unknown
406/tcp   filtered imsp
1277/tcp  filtered miva-mqs
2920/tcp  filtered roboeda
3580/tcp  filtered nati-svrloc
5440/tcp  filtered unknown
6510/tcp  filtered mcer-port
7019/tcp  filtered unknown
8200/tcp  filtered trivnet1
32776/tcp filtered sometimes-rpc15
```

None of these ports are shown when I run `netstat -abno | FINDSTR LISTENING`

How can a port my OS doesn't even know is open be in anything but a closed state? 
How is nmap seeing these ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When [Nmap shows a port as "filtered,"](https://secwiki.org/w/FAQ_filtered) what it means is that it received no response to any probe sent to that port. The usual cause for this is a firewall that is dropping packets destined for those ports, but it can also be the case when there is packet loss between Nmap and the target. Nmap usually does a good job of monitoring the network quality during a scan and increasing the number of retries when packet drops are detected, but if you use aggressive timing options like `-T5` or `--max-retries 0`, then some packet loss can be expected.

Firewalls block access to ports regardless of whether the machine they are protecting is using those ports. There is no necessary correlation between the output of `netstat` and the set of ports that a firewall allows or blocks. Also, depending on where you scanned from, there may be "firewalls" that you are unaware of: Internet Service Providers (ISPs) tend to filter traffic to and from ports that have historically been subject to abuse, especially for home (i.e. non-business) Internet access: ports 25, 113, 445, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that is reassuring. I'm doing the scan across my LAN, so I don't expect any interstitial firewalls except the windows firewall on the target host, and I would expect network quality to be pretty good, but I did have a lot going on during that period, so there may have just been too much traffic for my SOHO-grade switches to deal with. Perhaps the windows firewall doesn't integrate with the host stack quite as much as I would have expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there are different ways that connections can be filters- one would be to simply drop the packets, the other to send a rejection message.   I suspect these ports are sending a rejection message rather then just not responding.

(In the Linux world you can see this by using DROP vs REJECT - the former just drops the packet, the latter will send back a rejection message, presumably indicating the port is filtered).  You have not specified which OS you use, but I'd imagine the idea is the same regardless.

Comment: Well, be that as it may, it doesn't explain why the host does not believe that there is any software using that port. if there is no program using the port, you would assume that all unused ports would display as "filtered", not just the dozen or so that are. It is conceivable that the windows firewall is treating these ports differently, and is responding in some way other than indicating the port is closed the way the windows IP stack would (and apparently does for all the other ports that are not on the list), but that would be a silly choice on MS's part.

Answer (score 0):

"filtered" is not the same as "open". Add `--reason` to the nmap command line in order to see how nmap came to the conclusion "filtered". Given what you wrote the reason looks like "no answer".